# Static web project in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide, visual-web-developer

I am about to develop a sort of web application using only static files (eg. html, js & css). Is there a way to start this sort of project in Visual Web Developer Express?

I want to have all the niceties with intellisense, sulution explorer and whatnot but I don't want all of the ASP.net structure in the sulution.

Is thiss possible or is there perhaps another IDE for this kind of project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well Igues I found it.

In Visual Web Developer:

```
File > New Web Site > ASP.NET Empty Web Site
```

I'll guess it doesn't hurt to look one more time before you ask.
But someone might find this usefull in the future.

Comment: mmm I've installed Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Web Developer however neither of them offer the option 'File > New Web Site > Empty Web Site' - I can start an empty ASP website or an empty C# site but not a completely empty project...